# Alias meta tags

Tags: .net, metadata, sitecore, alias, sitecore6

I'm working on a bank's existing website built with Sitecore.NET 6.4.1 and I'm running into some issues with aliases.  They use aliases to setup more friendly URLs for their bankers' personal pages.  For example: www.domain.com/bankername resolves to www.domain.com/About/People/Banker-ID.  The issue I'm having is that the aliased pages that link to the actual pages do not inherit all the meta data in the  section.  Therefore I'm getting all the sitewide default meta tags rather than the personalized meta tags for the individual banker (i.e. Banker name in the Title).  The meta data is setup on the actual banker page and works correctly when accessing www.domain.com/About/People/Banker-ID.

Is there a way to have an alias inherit the meta data in addition to the page content of the linked page?

```
public List<string> getmetaDetails()
        {
            List<string> metaDetails = new List<string>();
            string metaTitle = String.Empty;
            string metaDesc = String.Empty;
            string metaKeyword = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                // get root home item
                Sitecore.Data.Items.Item homeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home");
                Sitecore.Data.Items.Item Item = homeItem;
                // get Page array by url
                string pageUrl = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.GetRawUrl().TrimStart('/');
                string[] pageArr = pageUrl.Split('/');
                //Removes '?...' after the actual path.
                for(int i=0; i<pageArr.Length; i++) 
                    if (pageArr[i].Contains("?")) pageArr[i] = pageArr[i].Substring(0, pageArr[i].LastIndexOf('?'));


                if (pageArr[0] == "Advice")
                {
                    Sitecore.Data.Items.Item AdviceItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Home/Advice");
                    if (AdviceItem != null)
                    {
                        metaTitle = FieldRenderer.Render(AdviceItem, "Meta Title");
                        metaDesc = FieldRenderer.Render(AdviceItem, "Meta Description");
                        metaKeyword = FieldRenderer.Render(AdviceItem, "Meta Keywords");
                    }
                    if (pageArr.Length > 1)
                    {
                        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pageArr[1]))
                        {
                            Feeds feed = new Feeds();
                            List<FeedItem> adviceFeed = new List<FeedItem>();
                            string sql = "SELECT * FROM  `web_feeds` WHERE url='" + pageArr[1] + "'";
                            adviceFeed = feed.getFeedFromDB(sql);
                            if(adviceFeed.Count >0)
                            {
                                metaTitle = adviceFeed[0].title;
                                metaDesc = adviceFeed[0].description;
                                metaKeyword +=","+ adviceFeed[0].tag;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // loop threw page array to find the item
                    foreach (string page in pageArr)
                    {
                        Item = getCurrentHomeItem(page, Item);
                        if (Item != null)
                        {
                            metaTitle = FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Meta Title");
                            metaDesc = FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Meta Description");
                            metaKeyword = FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Meta Keywords");

                        }
                    }
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(metaTitle)) metaTitle = FieldRenderer.Render(homeItem, "Meta Title");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(metaDesc)) metaDesc = FieldRenderer.Render(homeItem, "Meta Description");
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(metaKeyword)) metaKeyword = FieldRenderer.Render(homeItem, "Meta Keywords");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                metaTitle = DEFAULT_TITLE;
                metaDesc = DEFAULT_DESC;
                metaKeyword = DEFAULT_KEYWORDS;

            }
            metaDetails.Add(metaTitle);
            metaDetails.Add(metaDesc);
            metaDetails.Add(metaKeyword);

            return metaDetails;

        }
```

Comment: Posting the code which is used for meta tags generation would be useful.

Comment: I agree with the above suggested code post :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with for those interested.

```
        if (Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.AliasesActive &&
            Sitecore.Context.Database.Aliases.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl))
        {
            //Is an alias
            Item targetItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Database.Aliases.GetTargetID(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl));
            metaTitle = FieldRenderer.Render(targetItem, "Meta Title");
            metaDesc = FieldRenderer.Render(targetItem, "Meta Description");
            metaKeyword = FieldRenderer.Render(targetItem, "Meta Keywords");
        }
```